# Listing and deleting permissions using Google Drive API sometimes does not work

Tags: python-3.x, list, google-api, permissions, set

I'm using the google drive API to retrieve the permissions on a folder and then delete them.  Sometimes the delete works, but other times I get an error:
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1gJKxxxxxxxxxxxLgpz/permissions/writeremail%40gmail.com?supportsAllDrives=true returned "Permission not found: writeremail@gmail.com.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'Permission not found: writeremail@gmail.com.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'permissionId'}]">

```
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        page_token = None
        while True:
            perms=drive_service.permissions().list(fileId = TEST_PERMISSIONS_FOLDER_ID, fields='permissions/id,permissions/displayName,permissions/role,permissions/emailAddress').execute()
            page_token = perms.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break

        perm_id_list =[]
        for p in perms.get('permissions', []):
            if p.get('role') != 'owner': # put ids and emails for non-owner in a list
                perm_id_list.append({p.get('id'),p.get('emailAddress')})

        for id, email in perm_id_list: # do the delete using the id
            drive_service.permissions().delete(fileId = TEST_PERMISSIONS_FOLDER_ID, permissionId=id, supportsAllDrives = True).execute()
```

When I go into Drive and look at the share permissions, all attempting to be deleted are there. It's like the ids are not correct.  Help! I'm so frustrated!

Comment: I think I figured it out - but not sure it is correct.  I was using sets to store id and email within a list, and the elements in a set are unordered.  So sometimes id would be first, sometimes email. The permission was not found when email was used to locate and it must be id.  That is why an email showed up in the http request.  Goofy.

Comment: It was the difference between {}s and [] in this command:
perm_id_list.append(  {  p.get('id'),p.get('emailAddress')  } )  versus
perm_id_list.append(  [  p.get('id'),p.get('emailAddress')  ] )
I thought the brackets were needed for syntax.  Duh.